# REST/Javascript/Activiti - How do I find out what is wrong with my XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, activiti

This is my first time using XMLHttpRequest. I'm trying to get data from the activiti-rest api.This is the code I have so far, just trying to test it:

```
window.onload = function get_json() {

    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/tasks?assignee=kermit";
    var result = document.getElementById("result");

    alert(url);

    hr.open("GET", url, true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if(hr.readystate == 4 && hr.status == 200) {

            var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            results.innerhtml = data;

        }

    }

}
```

When I run it I get a blank screen and there are no errors or anything in the console. So I'm really wondering how I can figure out what I'm doing wrong. It's making this difficult to learn as I'm getting no feedback to point me in the right direction. I'm presuming that I'm making some rookie mistake or missing out on something big but I've only just started learning.

Comment: `hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);` makes no sense. You are making a GET request. You are not POSTing (or PUTing, etc) JSON to the server.

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't throw a reference error since `result` and `results` are different variables.

Comment: @Quentin Could you explain why it makes no sense? It's just that I wrote this code following a tutorial that did it this way.

Comment: You are claiming that the body of the request is formatted as JSON. Since you are making a GET request, the request doesn't have a body at all, so it cannot be formatted as JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss the `hr.send()`, otherwise the request won't be executed

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive.

The `innerHTML` property has capital letters in it's name.